# Ruby LSP (RuboCop) がうまく動作しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

## 目的・状況

VSCodeでRuby LSPを使ってRuboCopをLinter, Formatterとして使いたいです。

Ruby LSPから次のエラーが出てます。

- Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
- Ruby LSP client: couldn't create connection to server.
- The Ruby LSP server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted. See the output for more information.
- Pending response rejected since connection got disposed

とりあえず`Gemfile`にrubocopを書いてみたけど動きませんでした。

もう一つのワークスペースでは動作していました。

## 環境

- Ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 7.0.8
- rubocop: 1.56.2
- ruby LSP (vscode extension): v0.4.8

### VSCode

バージョン: 1.82.2 (user setup)
コミット: abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d
日付: 2023-09-14T05:55:25.390Z
Electron: 25.8.1
ElectronBuildId: 23779380
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621

### WSL on Ubuntu

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: ruby lspのことはわかりませんが、Ubuntuのコマンドラインからruby lspは動きますか？
lsp起動後に、いかのようなコマンドを入力して、何らかのレスポンスは返ってきますか？
content-length: 24

{ "method": "version" }

Comment: ruby lspはvscodeの拡張機能として導入しているので私の環境下ではコマンドラインからは動きません
https://github.com/Shopify/ruby-lsp

Comment: VSCodeの拡張機能も内部でruby-lspを読んでいるはずです。ruby-lspもGem賭して読み込んでいるはずです。先ず、開発環境構築時にGemが実行できるようにパスを設定していますか？

Comment: ほかのワークスペースでは動いてるんで、パスは通ってるはずなんです

Comment: たとえばワークスペースによって Ruby のバージョンが異なると使えたり使えなかったりする可能性はあります。また、Shopify.ruby-lsp が使う LSP サーバーと rubocop は別物です。クラッシュのログを見ないと正確には分かりませんが、質問者さんの回答を見るにフォーマッターとして rubocop が指定されているものの rubocop が用意されていなくてクラッシュした、とかかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の手順でhome dirにruby-lspのフォルダーができるのでこれでlspが動きました。
3.のところは `rails new` 経由でもいいと思います。

1. `bundle init`
2. Gemfileにrubocopを記述
3. `bundle install`